# Getting input into dynamically allocated memory then returning the pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc

Hey guys i've been having some problems with this problem. I have tried it many ways from looping with stdin and saving each letter to scanf(" %s") into an array then declaring the array as a pointer then returning the pointer. I have come close but have mainly had problems when having spaces in my string that I enter. The program needs to call this char* that gets the pointer to the string, twice and then output both strings line after line. Any help greatly appreciated.

```
char* get_input()
{
    char c = 'a';
    int counter = 1;
    while(c != '\0')
    {
        c = getc(stdin);
        char* d = (char)malloc(sizeof(char)*counter);
        *(d+counter) = c;
        counter++;
        return d;
    }
    return d;
}
```

So i was thinking something like this was the best way to do it but i dont know how to return the pointer out of the while loop and then again into the char*. What i really need is some guidance on the best way to store some input straight into an allocated array that will not waste any memory(it will know how long the string you entered is and allocate enough memory) i have also tried with scanf("%s") but i dont know how to stoe the data from scanf into a dynamic memory chunk.

And sorry dont have my actual code atm cause at work and my program is at home. Any ideas pls

Comment: Please show your code and explain what it does and what you expected it to do.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [**About**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the link describing [**How to Ask a Question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: @BenjyKessler Edited with a bit of code in the description and i am calling it in main like so: 
char* first = get_input();

Comment: Currently you are creating an array of `char *`. (And only once due to the `return` inside the loop, which is kinda useless.) Do you want this to return a regular zero-terminated C string?

Comment: @Jongware Ye i do but i have to save it into dynamic memory. Cant be saved into an array. So the pointer i'm returning should point to the first character right(start of the string)?

Comment: Do you have a limit for the size of the string? If yes: create a *temporary* string of that size, use `counter` to enforce not exceeding its length, and return a copy of it. If no: use  `realloc`.

Comment: there is no limit to the size of the string. I want to input the string then to allocate the exact amount of memory needed. How does realloc work i have never incorporated it into any of my programs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**your earlier code:**

```
char* get_input()
{
    char c = 'a';
    int counter = 1;
    while(c != '\0')
    {
        c = getc(stdin);
        char* d = (char)malloc(sizeof(char)*counter);
        *(d+counter) = c;
        counter++;
        return d;
    }
    return d;
}
```

Oh, no, no, no! You create a separate pointer address pointing to a `counter` size block of memory with each call to `malloc`, assign it to `d`, and then attempt to assign `c` to `*(d+counter)` which writes beyond the end of the current block, and which has absolutely no way of knowing what `d` was during the previous iteration -- **sigh...**

First, there are as many ways to do dynamic input as there are colors in a rainbow... It can be as simple and witless as using `scanf` with the `%m` conversion specifier (older versions and windows use `%a`). It comes with all the pitfalls that `scanf` brings with it. However, it can work:

```
char *get_input_scanf()
{
    char *ln = NULL;

    scanf ("%m[^\n]%*c", &ln);

    return ln;
}
```

But there are absoutely no limitations on data entry and very little control. (**note:** unless you pass additional information to any input function or use global `#define`s or variables, any input method will suffer from this limitation. Consider passing a max length to the input function, or make sure you validate the return)

You can also read **character-by-character** with `getchar()` or `getc(fp)`, or you can use **line-input** methods like `fgets` or `getline`. With any of these methods (except `getline`), you will need to allocate a temporary line buffer to hold the input, and then in order to limit allocation to the amount required, allocate your final buffer based on the `strlen + 1` of your input (or use just use `strdup`). As with all dynamic approaches, you are responsible for tracking it, preserving the start address to the memory block, and freeing the memory when it is no longer needed. Beyond that, the sky is the limit on what you do with the function.

An example of a dynamic input routine with `getline` could look like the following:

```
char *get_input()
{
    char *ln = NULL;    /* line buffer, NULL - getline allocates    */
    size_t n = 0;       /* initial buff size, 0 - getline decides   */
    ssize_t nchr = 0;   /* getline return - actual no. of chars read*/

    if ((nchr = getline (&ln, &n, stdin)) != -1)
    {
        /* strip newline or carriage rtn    */
        while (nchr > 0 && (ln[nchr-1] == '\n' || ln[nchr-1] == '\r'))
            ln[--nchr] = 0;

        /* if (!nchr) {             // do not accept blank lines
            free (ln);
            return NULL;
        } */

        char *input = strdup (ln);  /* duplicate ln in input        */

        free (ln);                  /* free getline allocated mem   */

        return input;
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

**Note**: as discussed above, `getline` imposes no limitation on how long the input string can be, so it is up to you to validate.

There is no limit on the number of different ways you can do dynamic input. (there are probably at least 1000 examples here on SO already) However, it all boils down to either **character** or **line** input, so make your choice as to what method you want to use and then write your code. Here is a small working example with the two different functions above. Look over the post and let me know if you have questions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *get_input();
char *get_input_scanf();

int main (void) {

    char *line = NULL;

    printf ("\nEnter input below, [ctrl+d] to quit\n");

    for (;;)
    {
        printf ("\n input: ");
        line = get_input();

        if (line)
            printf (" value: '%s'\n", line);
        else {
            printf ("\n value: [ctrl+d] received\n");
            break;
        }
        free (line);
        line = NULL;
    }

    if (line) free (line);

    printf ("\n");

    line = NULL;

    printf ("\nEnter input below to read with get_input_scanf\n\n input: ");

    line = get_input_scanf();

    if (line) {
        printf (" value: '%s'\n", line);
        free (line);
    }

    return 0;
}

char *get_input()
{
    char *ln = NULL;    /* line buffer, NULL - getline allocates    */
    size_t n = 0;       /* initial , 0 - getline decides*/
    ssize_t nchr = 0;

    if ((nchr = getline (&ln, &n, stdin)) != -1)
    {
        /* strip newline or carriage rtn    */
        while (nchr > 0 && (ln[nchr-1] == '\n' || ln[nchr-1] == '\r'))
            ln[--nchr] = 0;

        /* if (!nchr) {             // do not accept blank lines
            free (ln);
            return NULL;
        } */

        char *input = strdup (ln);  /* duplicate ln in input        */

        free (ln);                  /* free getline allocated mem   */

        return input;
    }

    return NULL;
}

char *get_input_scanf()
{
    char *ln = NULL;

    scanf ("%m[^\n]%*c", &ln);

    return ln;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/getline_getinput

Enter input below, [ctrl+d] to quit

 input: some string of input.
 value: 'some string of input.'

 input: another string that can be any length ........ ........
 value: 'another string that can be any length ........ ........'

 input:
 value: ''

 input: a
 value: 'a'

 input:
 value: [ctrl+d] received


Enter input below to read with get_input_scanf

 input: some input to show scanf will allocate dynamically as well!
 value: 'some input to show scanf will allocate dynamically as well!'
```